# C# How to make settings array WinForms

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, resources, boolean

I have around 10 settings in my project settings of type bool. I would like to have a List or an Array to store these variables but i also need whenever i change some of the array/list indexes value the setting value should also change. I currently have them declared like this :

```
private static bool[] CombinationAchievements =
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraight,
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetFlush,
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetFullHouse,
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetFourOfAKind,
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraightFlush,
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetRoyalFlush
    };
```

However when i change `CombinationAchievements[0] = true` the `Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraight` value is still equal to false. I can create a method that will edit the settings but it's mostly hardcoded  :

```
private void Test(bool[] editSettings)
{
    properties.settings.default.GetStraight= editSettings[0];
    properties.settings.default.GetFlush= editSettings[1];
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Just a pseudo code. However it doesn't look nice at all imagine if i have 100 settings.. All i need is something that can hold all my settings so the function can look like this :

```
private void Test(bool[] editSettings)
{
    List<properties.settings.default> thisIsNotHowYouDoItMate = new List<properties.settings.default>
    for(int i = 0;i<thisIsNotHowYouDoItMate.count;i++)
    {
        thisIsNotHowYouDoItMate[i]=editSettings[i];
    }     
}
```

The above code is what im trying to achieve of course this is crap but i hope you got the idea.

Comment: It is never going to be pretty as long as you have to call 100 property setters.  System.Configuration is feeble, a NameValueCollection is about as good as it gets.  Make it better by declaring an enum.

Comment: So there is now way to store them in array ? Also with enum i will have to cast (int) each time am i correct :?

Comment: maybe you are better off with your own configuration using xml serialization to the file ?

Comment: how can xml serialization help in my case :?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to go for Custom Settings with XML file as storage here an example how it could be implemented:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XMLConfigurationExample
{
    public sealed class Configuration
    {
        private readonly List<Setting> _settings = new List<Setting>();
        private readonly object _lock = new object();
        private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer;
        private const string FileName = "settings.xml";

        public Configuration()
        {
            _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Setting>));
            LoadSettings();
        }

        public object this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                Setting setting = _settings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == key);
                if (setting != null)
                {
                    return setting.Value;
                }
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                Setting setting = _settings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == key);
                if (setting != null)
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        setting.Value = value;
                    }
                    SaveSettings();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                {
                    _serializer.Serialize(fileStream, _settings);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // here your real error handling
                Debugger.Log(100, "Error", ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

        }

        private void LoadSettings()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    ((List<Setting>)_serializer.Deserialize(fileStream)).ForEach(s => _settings.Add(s));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // here your real error handling
                Debugger.Log(100,"Error",ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void AddSetting(string key)
        {
            if (_settings.All(s => s.Key != key))
            {
                _settings.Add(new Setting { Key = key });
            }
        }

        public void RemoveSetting(string key)
        {
            Setting setting = _settings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == key);
            if (setting != null)
            {
                _settings.Remove(setting);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting model:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace XMLConfigurationExample
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Setting
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And usage in e.g. console application:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.AddSetting("Test");
configuration.AddSetting("Test2");

configuration["Test"] = "value1";
configuration["Test2"] = 12.040;

// here your real output or using of the configuration
Debugger.Log(100, "Log", configuration["Test"].ToString());
Debugger.Log(100, "Log", configuration["Test2"].ToString());
```

Configuration should be instantiated only once in your application and used e.g. as singleton for reading and writing.

Comment: It's win forms can you edit the parts with console.writeline etc ?

Comment: Please check out my changes. Of course u will need to adapt the implementation to your actual winform application.